# Kivy - Draw Rectangle Around Text

Tags: user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm brand new to Kivy and trying to make a UI for a project. I'm trying to develop an understanding for how everything gets sized in the different layouts.

I'm having an issue where I have two labels side by side in a box layout (nested in another box layout). I want the 2nd label to have a rectangle drawn behind only the text. I can get 90% of the way there, but I'm stumbling over positioning the rectangle behind the text, since there is no "self.texture_pos" like there is "self.texture_size".

How can I dynamically draw a rectangle at the size and position of a label string, or am I doing this a really dumb way?

My .KV, sorry for the funky colors, as I said I'm trying to understand how everything is positioned:

```
#:kivy 1.8.0

BoxLayout:
    size: root.size
    pos: root.pos
    id: foo_bar
    orientation: 'vertical'

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: .6, .6, .6
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
        
    StatusBarWidget:
    ProcessValWidget:
    ProcessSliderWidget:
    StartStopWidget:

<startstopwidget>:              
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
                
        Label:                      
            font_size: 70
            center_x: root.width / 4
            top: root.top - 50
            text: "2"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,1,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos           
        Label:
            font_size: 70
            center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
            top: root.top - 50
            text: "3"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,0,1,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size 
                    pos: self.pos
            
<processvalwidget>:             
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
                
        Label:
            id: lbl_pval
            font_size: 50
            text: "Pressure:"
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
            valign: 'middle'
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 1,0,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size 
                    pos: self.pos
        Label:
            id: val_pval
            font_size: 50
            text: "100 PSI"
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: 0,1,0,1
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.texture_size
                    pos: self.pos
                    
<processsliderwidget>:              
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
                
        Slider:
            id: slider
            min: 0
            max: 100
            step: 1
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            
        Label:
            text: str(slider.value)

<statusbarwidget>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size 
            pos: self.pos
    Label:
        text: "STATUS BAR"
        text_size: self.size
        size_hint_x: None
        halign: 'left'
        valign: 'middle'
        padding_x: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `texture_size` to adjust the position of the `Rectangle`:

```
Label:
    font_size: 70
    center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
    top: root.top - 50
    text: "3"
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0,0,1,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.texture_size
            pos: self.center_x - self.texture_size[0]/2, self.center_y - self.texture_size[1]/2
```